# Win 7 shortcut to .jar file no longer works

Tags: java, jar, windows-7, shortcut

I have a shortcut on my Desktop to an executable .jar file.
This has been working for several years.
I recently had to replace my motherboard - and now .jar files will no longer launch either from a shortcut, or by double-clicking on them in FileManager.
I get a very brief busy cursor, then nothing.

If I open a command window, and type in the java command - it works just fine.
.jar files are still associated with Java as well.

```
C:\Projects\BelfryTabs>where java.exe
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe

C:\Projects\BelfryTabs>java -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

This command runs fine:

```
C:\Projects\BelfryTabs>javaw -jar BelfryTabs.jar
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to create a new shortcut?

Comment: Yup.  Still doesn't work.
The fact that double-clicking in FileManager doesn't work either makes me think there is something wrong with MS Win.